# Facebook Page Share in mobile

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sharer, x-facebook-platform

I have to share a website page on facebook. In desktop and facebook android app, it works perfectly. But when I'm going to share that page through mobile browser like UC browser, I can not get the url which I want to share. It messaged like "post not found". I know that I have to make setting in my favebook developer account and also have to put some code line in my PHP page. But how and where that I don't know. If anyone know answer then please explain or suggest me link from where I can understand from beginning. Thank You. Here is mobile screenshot.
[image]

After click on preview, I got this screen.
[image]

Comment: Please if anybody help me, then please help me.